# Dealing with const and non-const versions of data observer classes

Tags: c++, oop, templates, generic-programming

I keep running into the same problem when designing data-observing classes (like iterators), regarding the handling and conversion of their const and non-const versions.

Consider a class which observes some externally handled data via a pointer or similar (similar to `std::weak_ptr`):

```
template<typename T>
class observer {
public:
    observer(T* ptr) :
        _ptr(ptr) {}

    T& get() const {
        return *_ptr;
    }

private:
    T* _ptr;
};
```

This is all cool and dandy, except for when you want only const access to the observed data:

```
template<typename T>
void need_const(observer<T const>) {}

// Uh oh...
observer<int> o{ nullptr };
need_const(o);    // Can't do
```

One obviously loses the implicit conversions to const versions like with all the fundamental types (`int -> int const`, `T* -> T const*` etc). I have several ideas for how to work around this, but none of them seem ideal, and I was wondering what a good C++-style solution to this problem would be.

- A converting constructor for `observer<T>` accepting an `observer<U>`. Would work fine for some cases (and is in fact what is used in `std::weak_ptr`), except that it creates a new object, obviously. It wouldn't work for anything wanting to access the object via an lvalue reference, such as
  `template<typename T> void need_const(observer<T const>&) {}`.
- Instead using two classes, `observer<T>` and `const_observer<T>` which have non-const and const pointers, respectively, to the observed data. This is similar to how the standard library does iterators. This still doesn't solve the problem mentioned in the above point, leading to more options of how to design it:

  - `observer<T>` contains a `const_observer<T>`, using `const_cast`s to allow non-const access, and implementing an `operator const_observer<T>&()` for conversion for const access. Works perfectly, except the use of `const_cast` feels dodgy and inelegant to me.
  - `observer<T>` inherits from `const_observer<T>`, using `const_cast`s to allow non-const access. Again, this works perfectly, except it introduces inheritance, which is another whole kettle of fish to deal with.
- Something I haven't considered.

Comment: Your ideas with `const_observer` and `observer` sound good to me. If anything, I'ld say `const_cast` was tailored to solve cases like that!

Comment: This `observer` class looks like `std::reference_wrapper`. To be honest I don't get what is the issue with it since there is no problem converting `observer<T>` to `observer<const T>`. Maybe you can add `operator const observer<const T> &` into `observer<T>` to make in implicit.

Comment: @VTT I'm not sure I follow. Adding an implicit conversion like that would still have to create a new object, which work somewhat, but still suffers some problems as outlined in the first dot point.